# Read and Edit Charts from Microsoft Word using Apache poi 3.17

Tags: java, excel, ms-word, apache-poi

I want to read and edit charts in Microsoft Word Document using Apache POI.
I read many articles of apache poi 4 and plus which has XWPFChart Class to represent charts in word document but in the version poi 3.17 I am not able to find any charts.
So far I have written below code. Please someone help me write a code to get workbook object of the charts.

```
try (XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(fileName)))) {

        // output the same as 8.1
        List<XWPFParagraph> list = doc.getParagraphs();
        for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : list) {
            // System.out.println(paragraph.getText());
        }
        for (POIXMLDocumentPart part : doc.getRelations()) {
            if (!StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getPackagePart().getContentTypeDetails().getSubType(),"vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.drawingml.chart+xml")) {
                System.out.println("Name ->" + part.toString() + ", Class -> " + part.getClass()", Parent Part ->" + part.getPackagePart().getContentTypeDetails().getSubType());
                
            } continue;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: [Apache POI 3.17 is over 5 years old](https://poi.apache.org/devel/history/changes-3x.html#3.17), what happens if you upgrade to something vaguely recent?

Comment: I am working on certain RPA tool and in this all the jars are coming from some server I don't have access of. So I can't upgrade the version that is why I am asking.

Comment: Apache POI is open source, you'll either need to upgrade or do your own work to backport the feature...